# Isalpha is requiring an identifier

Tags: c

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

main(){
    float input;
    printf("Input: ");
    scanf("%f", &input);
    if (isalpha(input) || (input) < 0)){
        printf("Input is an alphabet or is lesser than 0");
    } else {
        printf("Input is correct. %f is a number larger than 0", input);
    }
}
```

I want the code to detect if `input` is a number larger than 0, or is it an alphabet. However, I am getting this error:

> 8: error: identifier expected

What does it mean to my code's execution? How am I supposed to run the code successfully?

Comment: Match number of parenthesis here: `( isalpha(input) || (input) < 0) )`.

Comment: `input` is of type `float`. Why are you checking for an alphabet? You need to check the return value of `scanf()` whether the input was successful or not.

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to input a letter, such as `a`? You can't use the `%f` format for that. Could you give us an example of input that should print the first message, and one that should print the second message?

Comment: mine has the same number of parenthesis too ```(isalpha(input) || (input) < 0))```

Comment: Exactly, you have one too many parenthesis. Should be `if (isalpha(input) || (input) < 0){` but we think that there are more fundamental issues with the code beside the fact that it does not compile.

Comment: @damix911 like if input is a or -3, the first line is printed. if input is 3 or 20.45 anything, the second condition is executed

Comment: What about the `alphabet` thing? What would an `alphabet` input be? The example you just posted has only numbers.

Comment: the posted code does not compiler, for many reasons, like extraneous closing paren ')', invalid signature for `main()`,

Comment: OT: regarding: `(input) < 0)`  the variable `input` is a `float`, so should not be compared to an `int`.  Suggest: `(input) < 0.0f)

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%f", &input);`  1) always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  Any returned value other than 1 indicates an error occurred.  2) The `%f` will not input a ALPHA character, I.E. the call to `scanf()` will fail`

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding;  1) Please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: regarding: *like if input is a or -3,*  the `%f` input format conversion' specifier will NOT input a 'a' (and the returned value from `scanf()` will be 0 when success for this statement would be 1.

Answer (score 3):

Correct parentheses in `if`:

```
if ( isalpha(input) || (input < 0) )
```

In addition, you need to check the return value of `scanf()` whether there was input or not. In the case of no input, the return value would be 0 or in case of multiple inputs how many succeeded. In your case, you can use the return value to determine whether a `float` was input or not.

The `main()` should return an `int` and always initialize your variables.

Example ([live](https://godbolt.org/z/r8Iwiz)):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    float input = 0.0f;

    printf("Input: ");
    int ret = scanf("%f", &input);

    if ( ret == 0 )
    {
        printf("ERROR: Input is NOT a float!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if ( input < 0.0f )
    {
        printf("Input is less than 0");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Input is correct. %f is a number larger than 0", input);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will not handle cases where a user enters something that is not acceptable for a `float` but starts with characters that are, such as “3x”.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I'm not sure if the OP was looking for that kind of input validation. That would be a nice addition though. You might want to post an answer including other corner cases as well. That would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your parentheses aren't opened/closed properly.
2. Maybe your ide/compiler is taking care of it, but it should be `int main()`
3. `isalpha()` will behave unexpectedly with float values. Try avoiding that.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are missing `int` declaring main,

```
int main()
```

Also,you have excessive bracket in line

```
if (isalpha(input) || (input) < 0)){
```

Scanf uses %f to read floats. What your program will do is accept any ascii character and I suppose that wasn't your intention.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure what you need, but you could try something like this as a starting point. It does not handle all possible inputs, and will erroneously classify an input such as `#42` as alphabet or lesser than 0, which is questionable, but you can iterate on this and hopefully get to a more polished version.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(){
    float input;
    printf("Input: ");
    if (scanf("%f", &input) && input >= 0){
        printf("Input is correct. %f is a number larger than 0", input);
    } else {
        printf("Input is an alphabet or is lesser than 0");
    }
}
```

**Explanation**

We save the value in `input`, if compatible with the `%f` format:

```
float input;
```

Prompt for the user:

```
printf("Input: ");
```

This condition is made of two parts; the first part is the `scanf`, that will try to read `input`, and if successful will evaluate to 1, which is `true`, so the second part `input >= 0` will be evaluated, and if `input` is indeed >= 0 we print the first message.

```
if (scanf("%f", &input) && input >= 0){
    printf("Input is correct. %f is a number larger than 0", input);
```

Else we print the second message.

```
} else {
    printf("Input is an alphabet or is lesser than 0");
}
```